# Convex hull of $\{ \Vert x \Vert = 1 \}$ is closed in strictly convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm trying to show that the convex hull of $\{ \Vert x \Vert = 1\}$ is closed in a strictly convex Banach-space.

I don't know how to tackle the problem. Are there any nice characterizations for a convex hull to be closed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think we have that the convex hull is $\{\|x\|\le1\}$ in **every** Banach space, don't we?

Comment: No, I don't think this.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment made no sense.

Comment: Yes, so $conv(\{\Vert x \Vert = 1 \})$ is contained in the unit ball. - How can we show equality?

Comment: @Steven: Consider the line through the origin and $x$. It should intersect the unit ball in two different points. (Here $\lVert x \rVert < 1$)

Comment: Yep, saw it now. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that the Banach space $X$ is not the trivial Banach space $\{0\}$.

Let us set $A = \{x \in X : \|x\| = 1\}$ and $B = \{x \in X : \|x\| \le 1\}$. Obviously, $A \subset B$ and $B$ is closed. Further, every $x \in B$ can be written as a convex combination of two elements from $A$:

- If $x = 0$, we have $x = \frac12 \, y + \frac12 \, (-y)$, where $y \in A$ is arbitrary (such $y$ exists, since $X \ne \{0\}$.
- If $x \ne 0$, it is a suitable convex combination of $x / \|x\|$ and $-x/\|x\|$.

Hence, $B$ is the convex hull of $A$ and it is closed.